# How do I get access to Castle DynamicProxy generation options within MOQ?

Tags: moq, castle

Does MOQ give access to Castle's DynamicProxy generation?  Or are there configurable static methods or something in the Castle namespace that would allow me to tune MOQ's proxy gen behavior?

**Some Background**

I am Mocking a WCF Service endpoint (`IWhatever`).  WCF automatically adds Async call back options for methods (e.g. `IWhatever.DoWork()` is also realized as `IWhatever.DoWorkAsync()`).

I'm looking to use the `Mock<IWhatever>` object while self-hosting this service mock'd; basically spoof this external web service to my system. However, when [self-hosted] WCF tries to create a `DoWorkAsync()` method; it already exists... which ultimately throws errors when opening the self-hosted/mock'd `IWhatever` endpoint. ((NOTE: I don't have access to original contract to use directly)).

Sooo.. looks like Castle DynamicProxy allows for one to define which methods should be generated (see: http://kozmic.net/2009/01/17/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-iii-selecting-which-methods-to/). I was thinking I would use to *not* intercept calls on methods ending with "[...]Async".  However I don't see where I would add this customization rule in the proxy generation within MOQ; hence my question.